# New to Angular 2 and troubled with HTML sanitization

Tags: angular

I want to display raw HTML which does not include any user input. I found that using Pipes is a good way to display it but is it still vulnerable against XSS attack ?

Comment: If the rendered HTML does not include any user input, I don't think you need to worry about XSS.

Comment: Thanks ! It was my main concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/security) states that

> Interpolated content is always escaped—the HTML isn't interpreted and the browser displays angle brackets in the element's text content.

This means that simple interpolation is enough and you do not need to use pipes.

Comment: I didn't know there was such an easy way to do it ! Thanks